# JavaScript error occurs in Internet Explorer 11 only when Developer Tools are opened

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a JavaScript error, occurring only for some users, in Internet Explorer 11. The error (according to the IE developer tools) is an undefined object.

> SCRIPT5009: 'AjaxControlToolkit' is undefined

The error does not occur for me (or the other dev) unless we launch the IE developer tools and then load the page. Once we close the developer tools, and reload the page, it functions fine. We have tested this behavior over and over and it is consistent.

Why would the JavaScript error only occur when we have the developer tools open? And are there any IE settings which would mimic the behavior of having the IE developer tools open (e.g. JavaScript processing behavior)?

We have tested several settings in IE (e.g. checking and unchecking "Disable script debugging") but have not been able to cause the bug when the developer tools are closed.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you!